# How can i access my web page from remote?

Tags: language-agnostic

I have created a web page and have put it under Inetpub/wwwroot/Test.
Now I am trying to access it from remote but unable to access it.
What are possible causes and how can i resolve them ?
Please someone help me out.

Comment: more details ? what server ? do u declare a vhost ?

Comment: By "access it from remote" do you mean browse to it using a web browser (eg FireFox)?  And if so, from the machine that is running IIS or another PC?  You probably want to add some more details to your question to make it easier to understand and thus answer.

Comment: yes I want to access the web page from remote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Windows firewall blocks accessing your IIS server by default. Try turning that off...

Comment: Is there any other option , except turning off the firewall?

Comment: Erm, you could try adding an exception. Goto Control Panel - Windows Firewall - Exceptions tab - Add Port - Name can be whatever (IIS or something like that), Port should be 80.